# Three rods A, B and C form an equilateral triangle at $0^{\circ} C$. Rods AB and BC have same coefficient of thermal expansion $\alpha_1$....

Tags: trigonometry, physics

> Three rods A, B and C form an equilateral triangle at $0^{\circ} C$. Rods AB and BC have same coefficient of thermal expansion $\alpha_1$ And AC has $\alpha_2$. If the the temperature is increased to $T^{\circ}$C, what is the change in angle formed by rods AB and BC?

Intially, the angle is $60^{\circ}$

Final lenghts of rods AB and BC will be $l_1$ and $l_2$ while that of AC will be $l_3$

Using cosine rule

$$\cos \theta = \frac{l_1^2 + l_2^2 -l_3^3}{2l_1l_2}$$

$$\cos \theta =1-\frac{l_3^2}{2l_1^2}$$

$l_1$ and $l_2$ will be equal 
$$=1-\frac{l^2(1+\alpha_2 T)^2}{2l^2 (1+\alpha_1 T)^2}$$

$$=1-\frac{(1+\alpha_2 T)^2}{2(1+\alpha_1 T)^2}$$

Now that I have initial and final angles, how do  I find the change in angle?

I know this question uses quite a bit of physics, but my problem ultimately boils down to the math of it. The question was not accepted on physics SE due it computational nature. I simply need to find the difference in angle, but I just need to know how to remove the cosine function.

Comment: Find $$\theta=\cos^{-1}(1-\frac{(1+\alpha_2 T)^2}{2(1+\alpha_1 T)^2})$$ then subtract $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

In physics, it is understood that thermal expansion results in only small changes and is usually treated as such. So, consider $\alpha$’s as small quantities and simplify  your expression

$$1-\frac{(1+\alpha_2 T)^2}{2(1+\alpha_1 T)^2}= \frac12- (\alpha_2-\alpha_1)T$$

Then, the change in angle is

$$\cos^{-1}\left( \frac12- (\alpha_2-\alpha_1)T\right) -\frac\pi3= \frac2{\sqrt3}(\alpha_2-\alpha_1)T $$

Comment: The answer given is $2(\alpha_2-\alpha_1)T$

Comment: @Aditya - The given answer may be incorrect. You may check the result against the special case where $\alpha_1=0$ and compute the angle change from $\sin\frac\theta2= \frac12(1+\alpha_2T)$

Comment: Can you please explain the last line? I am not sure what you did with the inverse function

Comment: @Aditya - it is the first order approximation for $\arccos(1/2+x)= \arccos(1/2) + (\arccos(1/2))’ x$

Comment: What is $\arccos(1/2))’x$ supposed to be

Comment: @Aditya - it is $\frac{d}{dt}\arccos(t)$ evaluated at $t=\frac12$ and $x = -(\alpha_2-\alpha_1)T$

Comment: Okay, I wasn’t familiar with these approximation methods.

Comment: @Aditya - it is just the Taylor expansion for the first two terms